# Extracting data from dictionary returned by json.loads

Tags: python, json, dictionary, python-2.x

Here is what I am trying to do:  Prompt for an URL, read the JSON data from that URL using urllib and then parse and extract the comment counts from the JSON data and compute their sum.

Here is what I have so far in Python:

```
import json
import urllib

serviceurl = 'http://python-data.dr-chuck.net/comments_42.json'

while True:
    url = serviceurl + urllib.urlencode(('sensor':'false', 'address' : address))
    print "Retrieving", url
    uh = urllib.urlopen(url)
    data = uh.read()
    print "Retrieved", len(data), "characters"

    try:    js = json.loads(str(data))
    except:     js = None

    print js.dumps(js, indent = 4)

    js = ["comment"][0]["count"]
    lst = list()
    lst.append(js)
    print sum(lst)
```

Here is what the JSON data looks like:

```
{
  comments: [
    {
      name: "Matthias"
      count: 97
    },
    {
      name: "Geomer"
      count: 97
    }
    ...
  ]
}
```

I am using Python 2. This is my first time doing this, so any feedback you can give me about this would be helpful, especially after the try/except statements. Thanks in advance.

Comment: And the question is ...

Comment: You did `js = ["comment"][0]["count"]` ... did you mean `js = js["comments"][0]["count"]`?

Answer (score 2):

`js` is a dictionary looking like this:

```
{'comments': [{'count': 97, 'name': 'Matthias'}, {'count': 97, 'name': 'Geomer'}]}
```

You can get the sum of all `'count'` values like this:

```
sum(nested_dict['count'] for nested_dict in js['comments'])
```

If there is a chance that one of the dictionaries in the list does not have a `'count'` key, use `dict.get` with default value 0:

```
sum(nested_dict.get('count', 0) for nested_dict in js['comments'])
```

Comment: Thank you for responding.  I am getting an error for the dict part.  Says there is no attribute in js.dumps(js, indent = 4).

Answer (score 1):

I've also done the same course and was on the same assignment. The answer by timgeb will get the job done in a smaller code. Alternatively, you can also try the following:

```
import json
import urllib
counts = list()
inp = raw_input('Enter a URL: ')

url = urllib.urlopen(inp)
data = url.read()
print len(data)

try:
    js = json.loads(data)
except:
js = None

comments = js['comments']
for comment in comments:
    counts.append(comment['count'])

print sum(counts)

#print sum(nested_dict['count'] for nested_dict in js['comments'])
```

you dont need to encode anything to the url, nor do you need a while loop. that segment of the code was used for using the google map API.

Answer (score 1):

My version of code:

```
import json
import urllib.request, urllib.parse, urllib.error
total = 0

url = input('Enter URL: ')
data = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read().decode()

info = json.loads(data)
number = info["comments"] #getting list of all the dictinaries
for i in number: #in each dictionary...
    needed = i.get('count') #... we are getting numbers from "count"
    total = total + int(needed) #summ all the numbers
print(total)
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on Mudit Sahni's code, but written for **Python3**

```
import urllib.request
import json

url = input("Enter URL: ")
response = urllib.request.urlopen(urllib.request.Request(url)).read().decode('utf-8')
data = json.loads(response)
counts = list()

comments = data['comments']
for comment in comments:
    counts.append(comment['count'])

print (sum(counts))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import urllib.request, urllib.parse, urllib.error
import json
import ssl

# Ignore SSL certificate errors
ctx = ssl.create_default_context()
ctx.check_hostname = False
ctx.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_NONE

url = input('Enter - ')
print('Retrieving', url)
uh = urllib.request.urlopen(url, context=ctx)
data = uh.read()

info = json.loads(data)
#print(info) #to see the info dictionary/object
#print(json.dumps(info, indent=2))  

count = 0
sum = 0

for item in info['comments']:
    num = item['count']
    sum = sum + int(num)
    count = count + 1

print('Count: ', count)
print('Sum: ', sum)
```

Comment: Why all the SSL statements? There is no HTTPS used in the question. Also, did you notice this is a five year old question :-)

Comment: Yes, I noticed, that is a five years old question. I was trying to solve an online course problem that is similar and solved in a generalized way so that it works for https also. I am learning python now and think this might be helpful to someone.

Comment: It's great that you want to help, thanks! But I don't think you should recommend disabling TLS certificate verification and hostname checking. With the advent of Letsencrypt it is easier than ever to do TLS properly, with trusted certs.

Answer (score 0):

```
##  http://py4e-data.dr-chuck.net/comments_42.json       total= 2553
## http://py4e-data.dr-chuck.net/comments_802780.json    total= 2670
import ssl
import urllib.request, urllib.parse, urllib.error
import json
total= list()

## Ignore SSL certification
ctx= ssl.create_default_context
ctx.check_hostname= False
ctx.verify_mode= ssl.CERT_NONE

## Access url
url= input('Enter URL: ')
req= urllib.request.urlopen(url, context=ctx)
html= req.read().decode()
print('Retrieving URL:', url)
print('Retrieved', len(html),'characters')

##accessing data
js= json.loads(html)
#print(json.dumps(js, indent=3))
for counts in js["comments"]:
    #print('Counts:', counts['count'])
    total.append(counts['count'])
print(sum(total))
```

Comment: it might help to include an explanation to your answer.. try to avoid code only answer

Answer (score 0):

```
import urllib.request, urllib.parse, urllib.error
import ssl
import json

# Ignore SSL certificate errors
ctx = ssl.create_default_context()
ctx.check_hostname = False
ctx.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_NONE

while True:
    count = sum = 0
    url = input('Enter location: ')
    if len(url) < 1: break
    print('Retrieving', url)
    uh = urllib.request.urlopen(url, context=ctx)
    
    data = uh.read()
    print('Retrieved', len(data), 'characters')
    
    info = json.loads(data)

    for item in info['comments']:
        count+=1
        sum+=int(item['count'])
    
    print('count:',count)
    print('sum',sum)
```

Comment: While this code may provide a solution to the question, it's better to add context as to why/how it works. This can help future users learn, and apply that knowledge to their own code. You are also likely to have positive feedback from users in the form of upvotes, when the code is explained.

Answer (score 0):

```py
from urllib.request import urlopen
import json

while True:
    url = input('Enter url: ')
    if len(url) < 1:
        break
    print("Retrieving", url)
    uh = urlopen(url)
    data = uh.read().decode()
    print("Retrieved", len(data), "characters")
    try:
        js = json.loads(data)
    except:
        js = None

    count = 0
    lst = list()
    for comment in js["comments"]:
        count += 1
        lst.append(comment["count"])
    print("count:", count)
    print(sum(lst))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import urllib.request, urllib.parse, urllib.error
import json

url = "http://py4e-data.dr-chuck.net/comments_1418532.json"
info = json.loads(urllib.request.urlopen(url).read())

comm=info['comments']
counts_list = [int(items['count']) for items in comm]

print(sum(counts_list))
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
import urllib.request, urllib.parse, urllib.error

import json

Sum=0

count=0

inp=input('Enter location:')
print('Retrieving ',inp)

uh = urllib.request.urlopen(inp)
data = uh.read()
info = json.loads(data)
print('Retrieved ', len(data),'characters')

for item in info['comments']:
    count=1+count
    t=int(item['count'])
    Sum=Sum+t
print('Count:',count)
print('Sum:',Sum)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
import json
import urllib

url=raw_input('Enter location:')
print 'Retrieving',url
uh=urllib.urlopen(url)
data=uh.read()


info = json.loads(data)
print 'Retrieved', len(info)
sum=0
counts=0
for item in info['comments']:
    sum=sum+item['count']
    counts=counts+1
print 'Counts:',counts
print 'Sum:',sum
```

Answer (score -1):

```
import urllib.request, urllib.parse, urllib.error
import ssl
import json

#to ignore SSL certificate errors
ctx = ssl.create_default_context()
ctx.check_hostname = False
ctx.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_NONE

url = input('Enter - ')
data = urllib.request.urlopen(url, context=ctx).read()
info = json.loads(data)
sum_count = 0
for a in info["comments"]:
    sum_count += int(a["count"])
print(sum)
```

Comment: using sum is a key word in python,This is against variable naming.  Assigning a value overwrites it the function... use another variable name